# Trouble setting up a linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Suppose I have two continuous predictors (A, B) and a categorical predictor (Subject) of a continuous dependent variable (C). Predictor A is directly manipulated in the experiment, and is identical for each subject. Predictor B is an observational variable that is different for each subject.

It is unbalanced by necessity: there are not an equal number of trials for each value of A (e.g., perhaps each subject saw 100 trials where A=4, but 80 trials where A=3.5).

I'm having a hard time understanding whether each of my predictors should be considered fixed factors or random factors. Is it acceptable to go:

```
lme(C ~ A*B,...,random=~1|Subject)
```

...or should A or B be included in the random effects somehow?

EDIT:

My description of each variable was unclear, so I'll give it another shot:

Suppose each Subject sees 100 trials (i.e., 100 values of C per subject).

- Variable A is a continuous predictor that is directly manipulated (e.g., think physical brightness of a presented stimulus, as measured with a photometer). For example, subjects might see 30 trials where A=4, 50 trials where A=3.5, and 20 trials where A=10. By "identical for each subject", I mean that if Subject 1 gets 30 trials of A=4, Subject 2 also gets 30 trials of A=4. In other words, my design is unbalanced with respect to the distribution of values of A, but not with respect to the distribution of values of A per subject.
- Variable B is a continuous predictor that is measured and can be different for every trial (e.g., think power of a particular EEG frequency at the time a stimulus is presented).

So, the values of A will be the same for each subject, but A might affect C differently for each subject. The values of B will be different for each subject (indeed, for each trial).

It is already known that A affects C. My interest is in measuring whether B also affects C, and if there is a pure main effect of B, or an interaction between A and B.

Comment: You say that a `A` is a continuous predictor but then note that you do not have "*equal number of trials for each value of*" it. I suspect you are binning it; this *usually* is not recommended unless you have a good reason. In general the model you describe seems reasonable.

Comment: @usεr11852 "Predictor A is directly manipulated in the experiment" so it doesn't sound like binning to me.

Comment: @Nicholas Root I think the model specification you have is fine, but you could also consider including a random effect for A if you think that the effect of A may be different for different subjects. If B is constant within each subject (e.g. age) then I don't think it would make sense to include a random effect for B, but I'm not an expert on mixed-effects models.

Comment: Do you have repeated `C` values per subject?

Comment: Added an edit that hopefully cleared things up

Comment: That values of B are different for each subject is not relevant. The question is if the effect of B on C is different depending on subject. If you can't answer this based on theory you need to compare models with and without random slopes and decide based on model performance (e.g. on AIC). The same for A.